# setting per series options when using native array data input format

Tags: dygraphs

Do the per series options not work unless the input data is in CSV format?

I have the following which attempts to plot a thin line and a thick parabola on the same graph:

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('graph'),
  [
    [1,2,1],
    [2,4,4],
    [3,6,9],
    [4,8,16],
    [5,10,25],
    [6,12,36],
    [7,14,49],
    [8,16,64],
    [9,18,81],
    [10,20,100]
  ],
  {
    legend: 'always',
    title: 'Data Chart',
    drawPoints: true,
    labels: ['index', 'doubleX', 'xSquared'],
    series: {
      doubleX: {
        strokeWidth: 0.5
      },
      xSquared: {
        strokeWidth: 2.0
      }
    }
  }
);
```

But both series just show up with the default display options. I'm not getting any warning messages or anything. Is there a way to get these to work with array input?

Comment: Your example code seems to work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/6018/

Comment: That's very strange since it's not working in my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/e20ldW

Comment: It seems to work with the dygraph-dev.js you're using - but not with dygraph-combined.js (plunker uses //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.2/dygraph-combined.js). However the rest of my code breaks if I switch to dygraph-dev.js. Do you have a recommendation on which one I should be using? Thanks so much for your help, by the way - really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're sourcing "version 1.2" of dygraphs, which is ancient. 1.1.0 is currently the newest. I'm sorry about that. See the note on the [1.0.0 blog post](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2013/08/announcing-dygraphs-100.html)